# Show form as a ToolTip

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to display a `Form` as a `ToolTip` of an `UserControl`. When the mouse is over the `UserControl`, the `Form` have to be show, and when the mouse leave that `UserControl`, the `Form` have to be hide.

I've overrided these events, in my UserControl class :

```
public partial class TreatedMetricsDisplay : UserControl
{
    private TreatedMetricsWindow _treatedMetricsWindow;
    public TreatedMetricsDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _treatedMetricsWindow = new TreatedMetricsWindow ();
    }

    protected override void OnMouseHover(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseHover (e);
        this._treatedMetricsWindow.Show();
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave (e);
        this._treatedMetricsWindow.Close ();
    }
}
```

No exceptions, but events are not called.

Comment: Does the tooltip has to be a form or some other user control is fine?

Comment: Some other user control is fine. Currently i've a form with FormBorderStyle set to None

Comment: Have you bound the event handler to the actual event, i.e. `this.MouseHover += new System.EventHandler(this.OnMouseHover);`

Comment: @BunkerMentality the base OnXYZ classes are what actually calls the event handlers. If the event handler works, so should overriding the OnXYZ class

Comment: @ZwoRmi do you get any exceptions? How do you initialize the form?

Comment: If your mouse is on a say button on the user control, user control's MouseHover event will not be fired. Is this causing you issues?

Comment: @danish So that mean that if in my `UserControl` there are some other controls, eg a Button x, the `MouseHover` will be catched by the Button x but not by the UserControl?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code sample that might help:

```
private void ToolTipControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AttachHandlers(this);
    }

    private void AttachHandlers(Control currentControl)
    {
        foreach (Control control in currentControl.Controls)
        {
            control.MouseHover += GenericMouseHover;
            control.MouseLeave += GenericMouseLeave;

            if (control.Controls.Count != 0)
            {
                AttachHandlers(control);
            }
        }
    }

    void GenericMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // no need to hide it if there was no form created in first place
        if(_form != null && _form.Visible)
        Form.Hide();
    }

    private void GenericMouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form.Location = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        Form.Show();
    }

    ToolTipForm _form;
    private ToolTipForm Form
    {
        get
        {
            if (_form == null)
            {
                _form = new ToolTipForm();
            }
            return _form;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Showing the Form will steal the Focus, It will get activated. So, it isn't a good idea to show Form as ToolTip. It will not behave as one would expect.

You need to use [ToolStripDropDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) combined with [ToolStripControlHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Which makes it possible to show any control as tooltip(not exactly).

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private ToolStripDropDown dropDown = new ToolStripDropDown();
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dropDown.Items.Add(new ToolStripControlHost(new ToolTipUserControl() { Size = new Size(200, 200) }));
    }

    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
        dropDown.Show(MousePosition);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        dropDown.Hide();
    }
}
```

`ToolTipUserControl` could be any `Control` which you want to show as tooltip.

Comment: This answer does not resolve the initial problem. But now it's helpful ! Thanks.